# Removing items from a list that appear in an external text file

Tags: python, list, comparison, text-files

I'm trying to take a list and compare it to a text file, removing the elements from the list that appear in the text file.

The code I have is:

```
baselist = open("testfile.txt", 'r')
twolist = ["one","two","three","four","five"]
for y in baselist:
    for x in range(0,len(twolist)):
        print("Working %s vs %s") % (twolist[x], y)
        if twolist[x] == y:
            print("Match!")
            remove.twolist[x]
baselist.close()
```

When I run this I can see in the output that it is comparing 'one to 'one', etc and obviously the problem lies in `if twolist[x] == y:` but for the life of me I can't get it to work. I've read and read and googled and googled but obviously I'm missing something. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

- opening files is usually better done with `with`
- when reading from a file, the newline char is not removed; so, for example, `'two\n' != 'two'` and your comparison-test fails. Use .strip() or .rstrip() to remove whitespace including the trailing newline
- `for index in range(len(mylist))` is usually a bad sign; better to operate on a list as `for value in mylist` and filter it as `[value for value in mylist if test(value)]`
- your first `print` statement is indented wrongly
- your `remove` syntax is wrong; should be `twolist.remove(x)`, and be aware that this only removes the *first* occurrence of x
- your algorithm is O(mn) where m is number of lines in `baselist` and n is number of lines in `twolist`; with a bit of care, it could be O(m+n) instead.

If the original order is important,

```
with open('testfile.txt') as inf:
    twoset = set(twolist).difference(line.strip() for line in inf)

twolist = [item for item in twolist if item in twoset]
```

Otherwise,

```
with open('testfile.txt') as inf:
    twolist = list(set(twolist).difference(line.strip() for line in inf))
```

Answer (score 0):

you've missed `rstrip()`.

```
if twolist[x] == y.rstrip():
```

And don't modify the list while iterating over it.

Better use list comprehension, and use sets to make it faster:

```
$ cat 1.py 
baselist = set([x.rstrip('\n') for x in open("testfile.txt", 'r')])
twolist = ["one","two","three","four","five"]
baselist = [x for x in twolist if x not in baselist]
print baselist

$ cat testfile.txt 
one
three

$ python 1.py 
['two', 'four', 'five']
```